# Prolog OR operator, to stop checking after first predicate returns true?

Tags: prolog, logic

```
border(de, fr).
neighbor(X, Y) :- border(X, Y); border(Y, X).
```

I want it to not check `border(Y, X).` if `border(X, Y).` returns true. I originally tried `border(X, Y) :- border(Y, X).` but that obviously ended up in an infinite loop.

Comment: See https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=once/1

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `once/1`, you can define `neighbor/2` as:

```
border(de, fr).
border(fr, es).
border(fr, it).
neighbor(X, Y) :-
    bagof(t, (border(X, Y) ; border(Y, X)), _).
```

Then you can still reason with `neighbor/2`:

```
?- neighbor(fr, Y).
```

Another without `bagof/3` but with `call_nth/2`:

```
neighbor(X, Y) :-
    \+ call_nth((border(X, Y) ; border(Y, X)), 2), !,
    (border(X, Y) ; border(Y, X)), !.
neighbor(X, Y) :-
    border(X, Y) ; border(Y, X).
```

Comment: Using `bagof`, to check all possibilities beforehand, would normally be very inefficient. E.g. if the first answer is sufficient, and bagof produces a list of a million answers.